# Unable to change Visual Code repository settings

Tags: windows, git, github, repository, bitbucket

I searched a lot for solutions for it, tried many ways to reset everything to 0.

I tried to set up visual studio (Windows 10 64 bits) to work with bitbucket without success.
It never accepts my password, even when I reset it.
Tried to delete any folders that would have settings without success either.

Tried to revert it to GitHub with no success either. Deleting the repositories did not improve.

```
    Looking for git in: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
Using git 2.18.0.windows.1 from C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
> git rev-parse --show-toplevel
> git config --get commit.template
Open repository: d:\
> git fetch
> git status -z -u
> git check-ignore -z --stdin
Missing or invalid credentials.
Skip fetch commands
Missing or invalid credentials.
Skip fetch commands
remote: Unauthorized
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://bitbucket.org/gusnd/mem/src/master/'
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
fatal: ambiguous argument 'master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
```

After unistalling git things worked fine but, if I reinstall it, I get the same issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found a hidden .git folder on D: drive root... and other files on program data, seems to be fixed